# JQL Results that show a rollover issue as associated with both the past and current sprint

Tags: jira, confluence, jql

I recently became SM of my team, and I'm trying to automate the way we make demo pages. Currently for a sprint, we make a confluence page, which we walk through with our customers. The previous SM inserted individual Jira issues for each of the stories that got done with a sprint and things that rolled over.

Well, I'm trying to get fancy and use JQL. is there a way to tie an issue from the sprint it got started in and to the current sprint?

For example, let's say Sprint October had issues A, B, and C. A and C got done, but B is slipping to Sprint November, which has issues X, Y, and Z.

Is there an out of the box JQL query without plugins that will show on a Confluence Page for posterity?
October Completed issues: A, C
October Incomplete Issue: B
November Planned Issues: B, X, Y, Z

I know the simple answer is to give the demo while the first sprint is open, and then close after the demo and rollover incomplete issues. But then if I were to go look at the confluence page the next day, the associated sprint for B has been updated to November, and won't show up as incomplete for October.

Or is there a way to export JQL to a confluence page that saves their status at a given time and will never update against their current status on Jira?

Now I understand why the prior SM made lists of issues individually and put them where they needed to go.

Answer (score 0):

"Well, I'm trying to get fancy and use JQL. is there a way to tie an issue from the sprint it got started in and to the current sprint?"

To see things that spilled over from a closed/previous sprint into the current/open sprint, the below JQL should work

```
Project = [EnterYourProject] AND sprint is not EMPTY AND sprint in 
closedSprints() AND sprint in openSprints()
```

Now to get a list of all items that were completed in a previous sprint, that can be done by manually writing and updating a JQL statement such as the one below

```
Project = [EnterYourProject] AND sprint is not EMPTY AND sprint = 
"[EnterProjectCode] [EnterSprintName]"
```

NOTE: that when entering the Project Code and Sprint Name in quotes at the end, it should give you a dropdown selection to get the unique Sprint ID to plug in

When talking about automation of being able to look at all of the issues in the previousSprint(), to my knowledge that would require a plug-in and not currently supported out of the box.